# Converting a date string to date type in vba excel

Tags: string, excel, vba, date

I have a column of dates that converted from MS Project into excel as strings.
The format that converted is similar to the following: "March 31, 2014 8:00AM"
I want to convert "March 31, 2014 8:00AM" into type Date but, since it isn't formated MM-DD-YYYY it is not letting me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does dt = CDate("March 31, 2014 8:00AM") in VBA work on your PC? It may not due to locale setting.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is in cell A2, for example, you could do the following:

> =DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))

Answer (score 0):

For a pure VBA solution, expanding on @cirrusone's suggestion, try this:

```
Public Sub lime()

  Dim dt As Date

  ' Convert the date string into a Date value.
  ' Assumes your date string is in cell A1 in the active worksheet of the active
  ' workbook.
  dt = CDate(Cells(1, 1))

  ' This will print the date with ".." as separators to show that it worked, i.e.
  ' it should be able to understand every part of the date string passed to it
  ' after having converted it to a Date value.
  MsgBox DatePart("d", dt) & ".." & DatePart("m", dt) & ".." & DatePart("yyyy", dt) & ".." & _
         DatePart("h", dt) & ".." & DatePart("n", dt) & ".." & DatePart("s", dt)

End Sub
```

I put some comments to explain what it's doing. [`DatePart`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/HV080557157.aspx) is a useful function to extract bits of the date (and useful to know in general).